# Таймер в приложении

Tags: android

Необходимо реализовать такое..

В Spinner есть следующие значения: 30 мин, 1 час, 2 часа, 4 часа.

Необходимо при выборе допустим 1 час, чтобы приложение фиксировало текущее время на устройстве и ровно через час после этого делала какое-то действие, скажем выключала воспроизведение. В общем таймер нужен. Как реализовать такое в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Копайте в сторону аларм менеджера и бродкаст ресиверов

Comment: Спасибо буду смотреть...

Comment: Ну либо можете попытаться через Services реализовать

Comment: Честно говоря не было времени даже про броадкасты толком почитать еще. А какой метод предпочтительнее в моем случае?

Comment: Читал статьи про планировщики и возник вопрос. А почему то что мне нужно нельзя сделать с помощью Timer и TimerTask? Никто не предложил их использовать.